# How to get error log in windows Azure server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-storage

I have developed test application to display claims of authenticated identity.
this application is working in local but when I publish to windows azure it gives some dot net error. Can Anybody explain me how to get error log in windows azure server?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Is this a website running under Azure Websites, an Azure Cloud Service or something you are running on an Azure VM?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you aren't looking for help with Azure Storage - or just in case you are I have included a detailed explanation below. For Azure log information see here: [Windows Azure PaaS Compute Diagnostics Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx).

If it is storage you are interested in, the following blog post provides a good overview of the logging capability: Windows Azure Storage Logging:[Windows Azure Storage Logging: Using Logs to Track Storage Requests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests.aspx).

Jason